# Getting a value out of an array

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array like the one below what would be the best way to get all of the `ListingCategory` items out of the array so I can use them in an if statement within a foreach?

**Array:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [ListingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ([0] => 532712629) 
        [ListingCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0350-5748-3400- ) 
    ) [1] =>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will cycle through all array items, and all of the children within each ListingCategory.

```
foreach($array as $item)
{
    foreach($item["ListingCategory"]->children() as $val)
    {
        doSomething($val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JMack I got it working without the ->children() is this an issue?

Comment: I specified children() because you are using SimpleXML. If what you're doing it works without it, you're probably fine.